# Clone Method Java

Tags: java, class, copy-constructor, rational-numbers

I'm trying to create a clone method that will take an already created Rational and make a copy so that in my main I can do something like this:

```
Rational r3 = new Rational(r1);
```

So far I created a method in my Rational class that will take in a rational as a parameter; however I am not sure how to make the new instance look just like the parameter.

```
public Rational copy(Rational aRational) {
int newNum = aRational.n;
 int newDenom = aRational.d;
 return (new Rational(newNum, newDenom));
```

}

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: This looks just fine to me. Is something not working?

Comment: "I am not sure how to make the new instance look just like the parameter" <-- eh?

Comment: Are you calling `copy(r1)` or `new Rational(r1)`?

Comment: Your copy method doesn't use this. Either make it static, or drop the parameter and make a copy of this instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> in my main I [want to] do something like this: `Rational r3 = new Rational(r1);`

This is not cloning, this is making a constructor that takes a `Rational` as a parameter. You can do it like this:

```
public Rational(Rational other) {
    n = other.n;
    d = other.d;
}
```

This would let you use the code to construct new instances of `Rational` from existing instances.

Note: It appears that both `n` and `d` in your class are exposed to users of your class as public variables. This is not ideal, because you have no control over the modifications that the users of your class may do to its instance variables. A better approach is to make them `private`, and add getters and setters to your class. This approach would let you detect attempts to set denominator to zero, which may be desirable.

Comment: @Absurd-Mind Absolutely, it does. My point was that the OP shouldn't make `n` and `d` private to control the process of setting them, not to make his constructor. I edited the answer to make this note a separate point.

Comment: Yes, you could also use the other constructor: this(other.n,other.d);